# Maven LifecycleExecutionException - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException - help reading this stack trace/debugging

Tags: java, maven, exception, treemap, concurrentmodification

I'm trying to build a Java 14 repo using Apache Maven and it looks like I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException associated with the use of a TreeMap(). I went back through my code and wrapped all instances of TreeMap() with Collections.synchronizedSortedMap() to avoid the exception, but my repo still fails to build. The line containing the error is not apparent from my Maven stack trace, so I assume the exception may be thrown from a dependency. I'm having trouble reading this maven stack trace in general, can anyone help me out? Is the issue with code in the repo, or a dependency, and if so, which dependency?

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.971 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-08T18:34:15-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:manifest (bundle-manifest) on project univocity-trader-core: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin: ConcurrentModificationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:4.2.1:manifest (bundle-manifest) on project univocity-trader-core: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Internal error in maven-bundle-plugin
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute (ManifestPlugin.java:134)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap.callMappingFunctionWithCheck (TreeMap.java:742)
    at java.util.TreeMap.computeIfAbsent (TreeMap.java:558)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.putResource (Jar.java:288)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:202)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar$1.visitFile (Jar.java:177)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree (Files.java:2804)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.buildFromDirectory (Jar.java:176)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:119)
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Jar.<init> (Jar.java:172)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.getOSGiBuilder (BundlePlugin.java:604)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.getAnalyzer (ManifestPlugin.java:285)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute (ManifestPlugin.java:111)
    at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute (BundlePlugin.java:364)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

Comment: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/3903 -> try to upgrade the version of that dependency?

Comment: @assylias this does seem to be the issue, but my project is not using bnd-maven-plugin, only maven-jar-plugin, and it's on latest release from October 2019. Am I just SOL on this until Apache releases a fix?

Comment: @assylias Also if bnd-maven-plugin is being used by some dependency within the project, will it be apparent from that stack trace somehow?

Comment: First is there a reason using an older version of the plugin maven-bundle-plugin instead the most recent one.. Second Are you building in parallel via `mvn -T ...` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise i am. getting similar error.